# My useMemo useCallback does not reduce the number of render. What is the correct way to use useMemo and useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function CountBtn1({ onClick, count }) {
  console.log('CountBtn1 render')
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{count}</button>
}
function CountBtn2({ onClick, count }) {
  console.log('CountBtn2 render')
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{count}</button>
}
function Counter() {
  const [count1, setCount1] = React.useState(0)
  // const increment1 = () => setCount1(c => c + 1)
  const increment1 = React.useCallback(() => setCount1(c => c + 1), [])

  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0)
  // const increment2 = () => setCount2(c => c + 1)
  const increment2 = React.useCallback(() => setCount2(c => c + 1), [])

  return (
    <>
      <CountBtn1 count={count1} onClick={increment1} />
      <CountBtn2 count={count2} onClick={increment2} />
    </>
  )
}
```

when I click Button1` also render

the log is

CountBtn1 render

CountBtn2 render

My useMemo useCallback does not reduce the number of render. What is the correct way to use useMemo and useCallback?

Comment: Where is your in memo component?

Comment: Wrap CountBtn1 and CountBtn2 in a React.memo, non pure components always re render when their parent renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your components with a memo:

```
const CountBtn1 = React.memo(function CountBtn1({ onClick, count }) {
  console.log('CountBtn1 render')
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{count}</button>
})

const CountBtn2 = React.memo(function CountBtn2({ onClick, count }) {
  console.log('CountBtn2 render')
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{count}</button>
})
```